# "Don't mind what she does tomorrow" but not "Don't know what she does tomorrow" Why?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, modal-verbs, questions

**Bounty note:**

This question is primarily about the acceptability of *will* in different types of environment. I have used the verb *mind* in my examples, but if you are an American English speaker, as opposed to a UK one, you might like to substitute this with the verb *care* (it doesn't make any difference to the question).

---

**The question**

Let's suppose that Maria the elephant is going to take part in a performance tomorrow. I am discussing potential acts for her, and my friend responds:

> 1. I don't mind what she does tomorrow.

Now that subordinate clause *what she does tomorrow* uses a present simple construction. If he'd said:

> 2. I don't mind what she will do tomorrow.

That would have been passable, but feels a bit wonky for this particular conversation. Here the subordinate clause  uses the modal verb *will* (in what's often called a future simple construction) instead of the present simple.

Now, my friend could easily have said:

> 3. I don't know what she will do tomorrow.

Here the future simple seems perfectly apposite. However this time, in contrast to the examples in (1-2), the present simple sounds positively wrong for this conversation:

> 4. *I don't know what she does tomorrow.

---

Ok, so far so bad. However, if we deconstruct the differences in meaning between the two sentences, things become yet more confusing. Here's why. Remember that I was discussing Maria's potential act tomorrow, which means that what act she's actually going to perform is completely undecided. Now if we consider this against sentences (1-2), this seems to be part of the problem with sentence (2):

1. I don't mind what she does tomorrow.
2. I don't mind what she will do tomorrow.

It seems, to me at least, that sentence (2) would be perfectly fine if what Maria was going to do had already been decided, but is wonky because nobody, including Maria, knows what she's going to do. So the *will* here would be ok if what she was going to do tomorrow was already known.

We can compare this with (3-4):

3. I don't know what she will do tomorrow.
4. I don't know what she does tomorrow.

Here the version with *will* is fine whether or not we know what Maria's going to do. In contrast, (4) can only be used in some kind of other situation in which what Maria does has already been time-tabled. So if she does the cha-cha on Tuesdays and the high trapeze every Wednesday and so forth, for example, but the speaker cannot remember which specific thing Maria does on a Thursday—and today is Thursday—then sentence (4) is perfectly appropriate.

So my questions are:

- Why does "will" sound wrong in the first pair of examples , and why does *not* using "will" sound wrong in the second pair? (given the situation described).
- What is it about the verbs *mind* and *know* (or *care* and *know*) that causes this difference?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68837/discussion-on-question-by-araucaria-dont-mind-what-she-does-tomorrow-but-not).

Answer (score 7):

The major difference between the predicates distinguished here with *Wh*-clause complements is that

- *not know* belongs to a class of predicates that takes a **Disjunctive** *Wh*-clause complement

whereas

- *not care* (in the US) belongs to a class that takes a **Conjunctive** *Wh*-clause complement.

[The difference is in the pragmatic nature of the *Wh*-clause](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CQ-DQ-New.pdf);
**conjunctive** clauses are factive -- they presuppose the identity and truth of their complement.  E.g,

- *I am aware of/They'll be surprised by/He doesn't care **what she does tomorrow.***
  In this example, the clause refers to the set of all actions that she is to do tomorrow,
  as a settled matter;  it's called *conjunctive* because the set consists of `A` **and** `B` **and** `C` **and** ...

while **disjunctive** clauses are indefinite, and presuppose nothing, E.g,

- *It's a mystery/I wonder/They don't know **what she'll do tomorrow***.
  In this example, the clause refers to an unknown set of possible events or actions;
  it's called *disjunctive* because the set consists of `A` **or** `B` **or** `C` **or** ...

Since the conjunctive clause is presupposed, there's no need for a predictive modal like *will*. But the disjunctive clause is indefinite, and its truth set may be empty ("..., if anything"), so the predictive *will* is necessary.

Comment: Before I'd asked this question, I thought something along these lines. This theory doesn't seem to sit very well, though, with *I know what she'll do tomorrow/ *I know what she does tomorrow* or *It's clear what she'll do tomorrow/ * what she does tomorrow*  or *We have already established what will happen tomorrow* ... Any further clarification?

Comment: _I know what she does tomorrow_ is perfectly fine, but it forces a generic reading, with a schedule involved: _She always does the mouse trick and the big spray on Tuesdays, so that's what she does tomorrow_. Again, factivity is involved; there is a presupposition.

Comment: The same goes for the *don't know what she does tomorrow* example, doesn't it?

Comment: Generic is usually an available interpretation if the predicate is a repeatable activity. [See here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html) for more (but still far from all of the) information on generic VPs.

Comment: Thanks @john for the links. What I'm trying to work out is whether the fact that conditional protases resist the use of *will* to express normal futurity is just part of the normal behaviour of *will* in subordinate clauses. ... I don't know if you have any thoughts about that?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Have you figured that one out?

Comment: @JK2 No, unfortunately not!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. You've probly seen [this link](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115478/15299), then. I think it's just a feature of _will_, btw. And I'm not comfortable with "conditional protases" used as if it were a syntactic term; afaics, since context is created bit by bit from any little pieces we can find, everything in a discourse counts as a conditional protasis, if someone can infer something from it. I'm a syntactician and I want syntactic tests for syntactic constructions.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't get "everything in a discourse counts as a conditional protasis, if someone can infer something from it"? I'm also wondering how to describe that feature of *will*? ('Cuz we wouldn't be able to say that it doesn't appear in protases/conditional adjuncts!).

Comment: In _if_ clauses, epistemic  _will_ does not occur. Modals are full of such disallowances; epistemic _can_ is an NPI. As for protases, I need to unpack; sorry.

Comment: @JohnLawler EDIT: How about in "I don't know if it will rain tomorrow"?

Comment: It's grammatical. It's asserting that the prediction is the speaker's. What's the question?

Comment: It's just that you just said "In *if* clauses, epistemic *will* does not occur."  ...

Comment: Sorry, misread it. That's not a normal _if_; that's the _if_ that you can substitute _whether_ for, in an embedded question. It's excluded from the rule because it's part of a special construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think it's more complicated than that. For example, we have "I don't care if/whether it rains tomorrow" where *will* seems to be similarly restricted. Also we have *whether or not it rains* versus *I don't know whether it will rain.* And we have *As long as/ unless/ on the condition that/ provided that/ assuming it rains*, where epistemic *will* is similarly disallowed. It would be fine in other adjuncts beginning with *because, although, whereas, even though, much as* etc

Comment: If you listed all the environments where _can_ is ability or those where it's epistemic,  you might get a similar list. Indeed modals are complicated. And the differences between _care_ and _know_ and _think_, among other predicates, along with negation, does intrude difficulties also.

Comment: @JohnLawler On the other idea in your earlier comment, I still don't get the "everything in a discourse counts as a conditional protasis, if someone can infer something from it" bit. Could you explain/give an example?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Do you remember Jon Hanna's answer back in 2015? There his answer was that _if I smoked here_ in _Would you mind if I smoke here?_ is not a complement of _mind_ but a conditional _if_ clause, and you agreed with his answer in a comment below that answer. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/217941/27275 If the same analysis is applicable to "I don't care if/whether it rains tomorrow", doesn't it explain why "_will_ is similarly restricted"?

Comment: @JK2 I wasn't paying close enough attention and I didn't know as much as I do now! I was wrong-but with a caveat. You can turn any old clause into a conditional by just sticking an *if*-clause on it (with a few grammatical restrictions on the  *if*-clause, for example, the presence of *will/would*). So even if *mind* can take an *if*-clause as complement, there's a homophonous sentence where the *if*-clause is a conditional adjunct. Having said that, *mind* requires the reconstruction of some sort of complement (null anaphora) if the complement is missing.

Comment: @JK2 So if I meet you and say "I don't mind", you won't have the foggiest what I'm talking about unless you can guess what it was I don't mind from the context. In your JH example "If I smoke here, would you mind?" a) the meaning is different because  *mind* there requires some kind of null anaphora. It could mean *mind that I was smoking* or it could mean mind something else. Anyhow, it's clunky. We can show that it is at least possible (in fact it's more likely) that the clause after *mind* is a complement by extracting a *wh*-word from it.

Comment: @JK2 Conditional adjuncts, like other adjuncts, are islands for extraction. **Which book are you leaving if I read?* <--That's not good. However, this seems to be OK --> *Which books do(n't) you mind if I read?.* Looks like that's a complement. Anyhow, GKP wrote a paper on sentences similar to your JH one where he argued that there is a *third* IF in English in sentences similar to (but not exactly the same) as yours. It's called *Implications of extraposed irrealis clauses* (1987). His student wrote a similar master's diss [Rocchi (2010) A third if?](https://tinyurl.com/2p347t6z).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't know if I'm talking about "a third _if_", suggested in the dissertation, but even if the _if_-clause now seems closer to a complement  of _mind_ (or _care_ in your example), there's no denying that it does look somewhat like a conditional adjunct. Then, isn't it possible to hypothesize that's why "will is similarly restricted"?

Comment: @JK2 There's a rule of interpretation for all those clauses (if you agree that the word *if* is not a preposition after all, but just an interrogative subordinator and that the 'conditional' meaning of *if*-conditionals is encoded constructionally, not in a magic word). So, yes, I believe you're right, the *will* restrictions could all relate to that single meaning/interpretation.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. that sounds like a resolution to my problem with "conditional" being treated as a syntactic entity instead of a pragmatic one. Though I'd still like to encounter one of those homophonous ambiguous sentences with _mind_ where the _if_ clause is a conditional adjunct, as if "conditional adjunct" were a syntactic description.

Comment: @JohnLawler Girl: The reason I mind hanging out with you in public is you're just not cool. Boy: Would you mind if I smoked and died my hair green? <--- Where the intended interpretation is "If I smoked and died my hair green, would you still mind hanging out with me in public?" The homophonous sentence where the if-clause is a complement has a non-conditional reading and means something like "Do you have anything against my smoking and dying my hair green?"

Comment: Thank you. Those two readings are almost certain to be intoned differently, though. Particularly if the guy has any brains.

Comment: @JohnLawler  I still don't get the "everything in a discourse counts as a conditional protasis, if someone can infer something from it" comment!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That makes two of us.

Comment: @JK2 Well, it might be because I didn't explain things very well in some writing I sent to John :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Whatever the reason, I think it's odd that he should not respond to your comment in any way even though this is the second time you've asked the same question, while he did respond to my comments on another post twice already clearly after your last comment to him a couple days ago.

Comment: I don't keep score. And I rarely look at who made which comment. I don't know anybody here personally, so it's all just text to me. I'm dealing here with the idea (which is novel to me) that "conditional" is a syntactic construction with syntactic properties (instead of a purely logical and pragmatic term, with no special syntax except certain governing words, like _if_). Use of _will_ with _if_-clauses is a fact about _will_ (and _if_), not necessarily predicted from any theory of modals or logic.

Comment: @JohnLawler If we're talking about the conditional construction, then all conditional adjuncts (which don't already require a different modal) have the very same restrictions on *will*, not just *if*-ones: "*whether or not/ however/ as long as/ unless/ provided that/ supposing/assuming Bob wins the lottery, xyz.*"

Comment: @JohnLawler Note that this applies to conditional constructions which don't have a meaning related to conditionality (e.g. so-called 'relevance' conditionals), and doesn't necessarily apply to other constructions which do. So, for example, neither clause in a sentence containing an *otherwise* adjunct is subject to these restrictions on *will*: "He will sign the declaration, otherwise they'll reject his application." Such sentences are not conditionals, because what might be thought of as the semantic equivalent a consequent/apodosis/result  appears in the subordinate clause, not the main one.

Comment: I see I am way out of date on "conditionals". I use scare quotes because I still don't see _conditional_ as a well-defined construction, or construction type, with syntactic constraints and conditions, and a short list of lexical items (mostly verbs) controlling it. I'm still looking for basic syntax here. I can see they're logically some modal variety of P ⊃ Q, but that's not syntax and has no syntactic outcome.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. You've lost me in your last sentence: "Such sentences are not conditionals, because what might be thought of as the semantic equivalent [of?] a consequent/apodosis/result appears in the subordinate clause, not the main one." Are you suggesting that _they'll reject his application_ is a subordinate clause in your example?

Comment: @JohnLawler Could you please show us a few examples of "some modal variety of P ⊃ Q" that doesn't have a typical conditional construction that resists epistemic _will_ (but not deontic _will_) in P? Because I can't think of any.

Comment: @JK2 Hastily written. I was analysing *otherwise* as a prep there. Oops. But in any case, it's not a conditional because it doesn't have a conditional structure.

Comment: Fergodsake, what's a "conditional structure"? All I see is references to it, rather like Jesus. Where are the definitions? Where are the restrictions? Where are the governing predicates? Where's the "structure"? We're all talking about meaning, not grammar.

Comment: @JK2: Does your request imply that you won't encounter any in the future? Oh, and btw, is _because_ a conditional word?

Comment: @JohnLawler You mean in some future English that's different from Present-day English? Then, does your first question imply that you can't produce a single example in PDE of "some modal variety of P ⊃ Q" that doesn't have a typical conditional construction? // AFAIK, _because_ cannot introduce a conditional clause. I can't even imagine why you'd even ask if _because_ is "a conditional word".

Comment: @JK2 You asked for an example of "some modal variety of P ⊃ Q" and I provided one. Or didn't you recognize it? And I'm sorry about your lack of imagination.

Comment: @JohnLawler Oh, you mean the example is this?: _Does your request imply that you won't encounter any in the future?_ Please let me know if this is your example, because, as you notice, I do lack imagination.

Answer (score 1):

'I don't mind what ...' can have two meanings, and these are informed by the constructions used.

'I don't mind what you are doing' usually means 'I am not troubled by the things I know you are doing'.

'I don't mind what you do tomorrow' means 'Whatever you choose to do tomorrow is OK by me'.

.......

'I don't mind what you will do tomorrow' is unidiomatic and thus has no default sense.

........................

'I don't know what she does' is idiomatic for 'I don't know what her usual practice in these situations is / I don't know how she earns a living'.

'I don't know what she does tomorrow' must have the sense 'I don't know what the timetabled practice for tomorrow is'.

'I don't know what she will do tomorrow' is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The question posed is about '*the acceptability of* ‘will’ *in different environments'.*

In one of these environments I believe that language comes up against what is currently termed ‘cognitive dissonance’ - a conflict not of logic, as such, but a conflict between personal value and personal action. It is the conflict of being obliged to do something one does not, personally, feel one should be doing. (Like uttering something that it is just not possible to utter.)

This arises, in this case, when someone is obliged to picture themselves in the far future, looking back towards the near future, in order to report a future happening as though it was a completed event.

I believe this is why, in English, we have a situation which some would describe as “possessing no future tense”. The reason we do not have what they term “a future tense” is because no such thing can exist. And many languages, I am informed, are thusly. My suspicion is, they all are.

In order to confidently make predictions about the future one has to project oneself into the far future, then look back at the near future (as though it were a past event) and report the occurrence of that event as though it had been completed, had been documented, and could be looked upon as past history.

Some have not understood what is involved in making a future prediction and their misunderstanding created the controversy of the Waw Conversive, which is ably dealt with by Robert Young in the preface to his Literal Bible. He blasts it to smithereens.

*‘I don’t know what she does tomorrow’* answers the question ‘What does she do tomorrow ?’

‘Does’ is a continuous matter. ‘Does she like ice cream ?’ ‘Does she visit the theatre ?’ ‘Does she have brown eyes ?’ It reports either a continuous state or a repeated activity.

The possible answers to *‘What does she do tomorrow ?’* are many and various :

‘I haven’t a clue; let me hop in my time machine and I’ll be back five minutes ago and one of us will tell you’ is one of the least exasperated outbursts which could result.

I would have to predict, in the future, what her state or her repeated actions will be and then I have to report them with the same degree of certainty that I report what I had for breakfast three hours in the past. Her eyes could be bloodshot, no longer brown. She may now hate both ice cream and theatre.

So my answer, properly punctuated, is ‘I don’t *know* what she ‘does’ tomorrow,’ (!)

How can I know ? How can I answer your question ? So ‘does’ is in quotes, because you said it, not me. And ‘know’ is in italics because I really do want to get across to you that *I don’t know !*

*I don’t mind what she does tomorrow* - my mind is completely detached from the future event and I am comfortable with that. No problem. She can do what she likes; polish the time machine, maybe. (Spoiler alert : we need it again.)

*I don’t know what she does tomorrow* - haven’t a clue, so I need not engage my sensitive cognitive faculties and they, thus, will not become dissonant. I am totally disengaged from tomorrow. It can be worded 'I don't know what she will do tomorrow' and it doesn't matter. I still do not have to predict anything.

*I don’t mind what she will do tomorrow.* ‘Will’ is her will, not mine. She will do fifty somersaults tomorrow (but only if she wills to do it). If somebody else wills to shoot her between the eyes, she won’t be doing a thing. So the blue button gets you into the future and the green one gets you back again (don’t touch the red one). Once you’re back and can tell me what she (and everybody else in the world) will be willing to do tomorrow - at that point I’ll tell you whether I mind or not.

We are creatures of the present (with memories). This is all we know. It is all we can know.
It is all that language will let us report. And if we try to bend language, we become dissonant

Answer (score 1):

The following sentence is unidiomatic in English:

> I don't mind what **she will** do tomorrow. NO

But the sentence can have a future meaning if we add the auxiliary "will" ***before*** the verb *mind*

> I **won't** mind what she does tomorrow.

Today, the more common response would be

> I don't mind what **she's doing** tomorrow.

[Cambridge Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-nouns/mind) contains a note on the usage of ***mind***

> **Warning:**
>   When we refer to the future, we use present (not future) verb forms after mind:
>
> ***I don’t mind*** what day they come and stay as long as it’s not Tuesday 12th because I’m away.
>
> **Not**: … what day they will come and stay …

I suspect that **do not mind**, is a relatively recent development stemming from its more polite and formal equivalent  **would not mind**, which is used to make polite (and sometimes hesitant) requests

> **A:** Would you mind if I open the window?
>   **B:** No, but **I should mind** if you were to leave it open all night.

From *[Fairy Birds from Fancy Islet, or the Children in the Forest](https://books.google.it/books?id=p2tiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22would%20not%20mind%22%20%20%22should%20mind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiExq3X88rXAhVHOBQKHXIxAao4ChDoAQgxMAI#v=onepage&q=%22would%20not%20mind%22%20%20%22should%20mind%22&f=true)*, dated 1846, the phrase *I should mind*  has a future meaning. Today, the “I don't think” would probably be omitted, and “I should mind in the least” would be replaced with *[I don't mind in the slightest](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/not_in_the_slightest)*

> “I do not think,” said Alice “**I should mind** in the least **having** my wings nailed on.” “Should you not?” said Jim, (half ashamed of his cowardice;) “ yes, but you would, though.” “No.” said Alice. “I am sure I shall not: I will have the wings nailed on directly, if the grey bird think it the best way.” […]
>
> “Why,” said Jim, “you know very well, that your saying **you would not mind having** the wings nailed on your shoulders, must make me appear very cowardly, so if you did not feel afraid, you should not have said so, for my sake.”

For the "don't know" construction, the present progressive tense, which is also used to express  future meaning, sounds far more natural and logical than “I don't mind/know what she does tomorrow”

> I don't know what **she's doing** tomorrow
>   I don't mind what **she's doing** tomorrow